# jquery-ui .tabs ajax load specific content of page?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to use jQuery UI's .tabs() to obtain content via AJAX, but the default behavior is to grab the entire page's content. **How would I obtain content from a specific #id and/or multiple #id's?**

I have a feeling I will need to use the `load:` event (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-load), but *I need an assist figuring this out*.

Example:

The Page with the tabs that is getting and displaying the tabbed content. I have placed #content after the first #the_tabs link to retrieve in an attempt to obtain that specific region of the content, but the entire page is still loaded.

```
<div id="tabs">

    <div id="tabs_display">

    </div>

    <ul id="the_tabs">
        <li><a href="testcontent.html#content" title="tabs display"><span>1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="testcontent2.html" title="tabs display"><span>2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="testcontent.html" title="tabs display"><span>3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="testcontent2.html" title="tabs display"><span>4</span></a></li>
   </ul>

</div><!-- /#tabs -->
```

The page being retrieved by the previous markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Remote HTML Page Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            I want this content
        </div>
        <div id="other_stuff">
            Not this content    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the JS (for setup purposes):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* Tabs
    --------------------*/
    $(function() {

        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jquery-UI 1.9, "ajaxOptions" is depreciated; so instead the code below worked for me:
(ref: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#the_tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.ajaxSettings.dataType = 'html';
                    ui.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(data) {
                            return $(data).filter("#content").html();
                    };
            }      
    });
});
```

Comment: Update:
return $(data).find('#content');  also worked better in my case. 
Whether to use filter or find, seems to depend on the structure of the HTML returned:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245231/how-do-i-filter-the-returned-data-from-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
/* Tabs
--------------------*/
var $tabs = $('#the_tabs').tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataFilter: function(data, type){
            return $(data).filter("#content").html();
        }
    }
});
```

});

Solution props to *Supavisah* in #jquery on irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck using .find, rather than .filter. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#the_tabs').tabs({           
        ajaxOptions: {
                cache : true,
                dataFilter: function(data){
                        return $(data).find('#content');
                },
        }
});    
});
```