# How do I filter the returned data from jQuery.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

When using the `jQuery.ajax()` method, I am struggling to filter the data that is returned to get exactly what I need. I know this is easy using `.load()` and probably the other jQuery AJAX methods but I need to use `.ajax()` specifically.

For example I know that this works;

```
var title = $(data).filter('title'); // Returns the page title
```

But what if I just want the contents of a div with id="foo"?

```
var foo = $(data).filter('#foo'); // None of these work
var foo = $(data).find('#foo');   //
var foo = $('#foo', data);        //
```

Ideally, I want one method into which I can pass a normal jQuery selector, which will work for selecting titles, divs, or any other element that jQuery can select. This is so that I can pass in any string into my own ajax function - eg;

```
myApp.ajax({
    url: 'myPage.html',
    filterTitle: 'title',
    filterContent: '#main-content'
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either `$(data).find('#foo');` or `$(data).filter('#foo');` **must** work. There is no way that none of those two work. Are you sure that you have a #foo element on the retrieved page?

Comment: They both seem to return an empty object. When using Chrome to watch the variable foo, it is shown as Object[0] and expanding it reveals context: undefined and length: 0. This is true for 'find' and 'filter'. Logging foo.html() returns null.

Comment: that object is not empty at all. Please see my answer for a working sample.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm sure there's the relevant element in the page. It's actually '.ops_datagrid' but I'm sure. There is another property under Object[0] called prevObject. It is an array containg 'Comment', 'Text', HTMLMetaElement', 'Text', 'HTMLTitleElement', 'Text', 'HTMLDivElement', 'Text', 'HTMLParagraphElement' etc...

Comment: The first div element has a property textContent '.ops_datagrid'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The use of `filter()` vs. `find()` depends on the structure of your retrieved HTML page. For example, if this is the retrieved page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Foo</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="body"> content </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tooltip"> tooltip </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to select the top-level elements = elements that are direct children of `<body>` - in this example: `#wrap` or `#tooltip` - then you have to use `filter()`.

If you want to select other elements - in this example: `#header`, `<h1>`, `#body`, ... - then you have to use `find()`.

I you don't know whether your element is a child of `<body>` or not, you could use this "hack":

`$("<div>").html(data).find( selector );`

By using this work-around, you always get the elements via `find()`.

Comment: For anyone else, Matts answer below explains the same method in a different way if it helps

Comment: Thanks for this post, works weel. Just a minor detail, you might want to use $('<div/>') instead of $('<div>') just to be on safe side.

Comment: @Dan I believe `$('<div>')` is safe. If you pass in a single tag into the `$` fuction, like so: `$('<foo>')`, jQuery will execute this: `document.createElement('foo')`.

Answer (score 7):

The `jQuery.load` method uses the following code:

```
// If successful, inject the HTML into all the matched elements
if ( status === "success" || status === "notmodified" ) {
  // See if a selector was specified
  self.html( selector ?
    // Create a dummy div to hold the results
    jQuery("<div />")
      // inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
      // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
      .append(res.responseText.replace(rscript, ""))

      // Locate the specified elements
      .find(selector) :

    // If not, just inject the full result
    res.responseText );
}
```

I.e it appends the full response to a DIV it creates, and then uses `find(selector)` on that.

So you should be looking at something like:

```
var foo = $('<div />').html(data).find('#foo'); // This looks like it'll work!
```

Bit of a hack from jQuery's point of view!

Comment: That's great, thank you. I've given top answer to Sime Vidas above simply because he got there first. The extra info is appreciated though.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I was able to get it working thanks to @Matt

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#foo').html(
            $('<div />').html(data).find('#foo').html()
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any special functionality given by the full `$.ajax` method, you should give `$.load()` a try:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(data).filter("#foo").text();
```

I am using this to filter the result of an ajax call that return an HTML conent

Comment: This just returns an empty string.

Comment: This works very well in my case. You did not posted any detail on your markup sample...