# How to get an element with selector after using jquery ajax? $.ajax()

Tags: jquery

I want to get a div element with an ID after calling $.ajax()
Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({

  url: "PO_Header.php",
  data: "supplier="+selectedId,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#PO_Header").empty(); 

    $("#PO_Header").append(html);

  }
});
```

`$("#PO_Header").append(html);` will append the entire html page, what I want to have is get an element with a specific id. Let's say in`PO_Header.php`a div element with an `id='mydiv'` would be injected in my current page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245231/how-do-i-filter-the-returned-data-from-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's load:

```
$('#PO_Header').load('PO_Header.php #mydiv', { 'supplier': selectedId } );
```

It allows you to load page fragments.  As their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) points out:

> **Loading Page Fragments** 
>   The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is
>   achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more
>   space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string
>   following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that
>   determines the content to be loaded.

It will therefore only inject `<div id="myDiv"></div>` from PO_Header.php into your element.

Comment: so what's the difference between load() and ajax() ? Thank you for providing me with a helpful solution.

Comment: `$.ajax()` is the general function jQuery provides to handle the  XmlHttpRequest object. But they added a whole bunch of more precise functions to enable people to get what they want out of it without lots of unnecessary parameters.  So `$.load()` is just a more precise and specified function of `$.ajax()` which enables you to fetch data from a server file and insert it into a DOM element.

Comment: Now all I have to do is use $_POST on my php page because I'm passing a data. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for this.

> **Loading Page Fragments**
>
> The **.load()** method, unlike [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.
>
> Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Basically you can use it like this:

```
$('#PO_Header').load('PO_Header.php #mydiv', { 'supplier': selectedId } );
```

To disable `cache` you can use at the start of your code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```

**EDIT:**

**.load()** is roughly the same as **.get()** except for a couple of reasons:

1. **.load()** has an implicit callback function which set the returned HTML content into the supplied element when a successful response occurs.
2. It has a special syntax for the `url` parameter for specifying just a determined portion of the returned document to be inserted.
3. Default method is `GET`. Unless the `data` parameter is passed as an object then a `POST` method is used.

Comment: so what's the difference between load() and ajax() ? Thank you for providing me with a helpful solution.

Comment: folllow up, when should I use ajax over load

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to bind to ajax loaded elements in an external function and call that in my success function.

```
function binder(){
  $("#mydiv")....do something here
}

$.ajax({

  url: "PO_Header.php",
  data: "supplier="+selectedId,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#PO_Header").empty(); 

    $("#PO_Header").append(html);
    binder();

  }
});
```

Comment: The question is how to select the "#mydiv" element from the html returned by the Ajax call, not how to manipulate an existing $("#mydiv") jquery element.

Comment: @Simon, That is exactly what this does. The binding function is not called until the ajax success function. Maybe I am not understanding your comment.

Comment: I think the original author wants to select the #mydiv element from the ajaxed HTML *before* it is appended to #PO_Header.  At least that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({

  url: "PO_Header.php",
  data: "supplier="+selectedId,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){

    var new_html = $(html).find('#mydiv').html();

    $("#PO_Header").empty(); 

    $("#PO_Header").append(new_html);

  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it and what it does is it injects the entire html page not just the specified div

Comment: I amended the variable names to make it more clear what is going on.  I can assure you it works as I use this technique in my own application.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example from CSS-Tricks to be very helpful -

http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/