# How do I filter body html the returned data from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxhr

My purpose is, I want to take specific html out from data and update that area only.

[How do I filter the returned data from jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245231/how-do-i-filter-the-returned-data-from-jquery-ajax)

This link is a old post but I do have the exactly same problem.

The solution giving from the link is `$("[ref=B]").html(data).find( '[ref=A]' );`

However, if I do so, the entire page will write on `<span ref='B'>` first then find the selector inside of it.....

The alternative way to only find '[ref=A]' is

```
html = $(data).filter('[ref=B]').find('[ref=A]').html() // this way will work
```

none of these will work

```
$(data).find('[ref=A]').html();
$(data).filter('[ref=A]').html();
$(data).filter('body').html();
$(data).find('body').html();
```

HTML

```
`<body>

<span ref='B'><span ref='A'>abc</span></span>

</body>`
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
$.get(window.location.pathname + window.location.search, function(data){ alert(data);});
 });
```

Returned Data

```
<html>
<body>
    <span ref='B'><span ref='A'>abc</span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, is there a solution to filter body`s html from data which returned from $.ajax?? like

```
body_html = $(data).???????
```

then I can do whatever I want, like

```
body_html.find('xxxx');
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: What's the value for data? Is the markup that's being returned valid?

Comment: Yes, the value of data is correct, the entire loaded html

Comment: Please post what exactly you get from GET request. `$(data).find('[ref=A]').html();` should work!

Comment: if you need to filter the data response, the data is probably broken and you would be better with a json response

Comment: @Till are you pre-loading a new Document using XHR for that, then you will apply in the body, or you just whant to extract some parts of XHR data result? My example work for both, but if you will append the full document, has better way to do it, I can show how.

Comment: `find()` works with no problem on your sample : http://jsfiddle.net/vM8V4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [DocumentFragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3) to simulate your html and do your search without appending it to the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

```
// Create your DocumentFragment to be able to work without DOM
var body_html = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Convert and append data from your jQuery to work with fragment
body_html.appendChild($(data)[0]);

// Now you can select using your jQuery
var $body_html = $(body_html);

// Now you can use the find or whatever you want, like if it was in the DOM
$body_html.find('.foo');

// Or you can append in your current document, 
// but attention, after it the fragment reference is erased
$body_html.appendTo(document.body); 
// now you need to get reference again from body, 
// because your fragment doesn't exists anymore.

// So... if you try:
console.log(body_html); // undefined
console.log($body_html); // jquery over undefined, probably just a jquery useless

// At this point you will need to reference from DOM to continue manipulation
$body_html = $(document.body);
// Now I'm ready to continue the work
// This var is like your DocumentFragment, but already on DOM.
```

You also can do a filter in jQuery templating `$(data).filter('.foo')` but as you can see in this **[tests](http://jsperf.com/jquery-documentfragment-vs-jquery-template)**, your performance will drop a lot.

Comment: I've fixed the example for you @Till

Answer (score 2):

```
$("[ref=B]").append($(data).find("[ref=A]"));
```

The way you do it in your question, the last part `find( '[ref=A]' )` is useless.

[Edit] Also, the other question is more than 2 years old. For recent versions of jQuery you might need additional quotes:

```
$("[ref='B']").append($(data).find("[ref='A']"));
```