# How to have more than 1 output for this simple ajax?

Tags: ajax

This is a script I learnt from w3schools to load in AJAX.

```
document.getElementById("sendInvoiceButton").innerHTML = '';
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("invoiceIDStatus").innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("invoiceIDStatus").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

  var invoiceID = document.getElementById("cred_form_4684_1_wpcf-ticket-invoice-id").value;
  var text = "invoiceID=" + encodeURIComponent(invoiceID);
  document.getElementById("invoiceIDStatus").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.lessons.com.sg/freshbooks/demo_wait.gif" />';
  xmlhttp.open("POST","/freshbooks/getInvoice.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send(text);
}
```

I can only output 1 xmlhttp.responseText;

I want to send the invoice number to a textbox too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

the simple way

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    ...
    document.getElementById("yourTextboxId").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

or if with textbox you mean textfield

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    ...
    document.getElementById("yourTextfieldId").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

---

I suggest to use jquery, is more simple and cross browser compatible

with jquery this would be

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/freshbooks/getInvoice.php',
    method:'POST',
    data: {invoiceID: $('#cred_form_4684_1_wpcf-ticket-invoice-id').val()},
    success: function(data) { 
       $('#invoiceIDStatus').html(data);
       $('#yourTextfieldId').val(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but where to place this code? should I replace some of my codes or add on?

Comment: For your first suggestion, it seem like I can choose either the status or the textfield, which I want both. The second, I don't really underdstand the code, would try but not sure where/how it fits

Comment: i updated the answer so it's more clear where it goes. The second is a replacement for your code, but you have to use jquery a javascript framework http://jquery.com/. I would suggest to learn and use jquery

Comment: I can't say that your answer is right yet. E.g the data returned for my status is "Invoice created", and the textfield should be e.g. "56519" (the invoice number)..

Comment: give me your response data. from your question i cannot figure out what your data looks like. Is it xml, json, plain? From your question it seems like you have plain respone and you want to display it in a field

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the structure of data that you are receiving but you could send it html formatted and then  use `find()` to split it and put in different input fields.

Comment: here you can find some examples :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245231/how-do-i-filter-the-returned-data-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: Is it common to use this method? I thought it was a newbie method =x

Comment: Well the ajax response comes all together in xmlhttp.responseText , there is no way to receive different responses with your ajax function. If you don't like to filter the data in that way you can always work with regular expressions :) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp