# Where can I put .filter method in my AJAX request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a "GET" request to retrieve information from this [API](https://www.reddit.com/r/dogs.json?jsonp)

The "GET"request is fine, but some objects don't have image thumbnails to put as my source, and I want to filter them out, but can't seem to know where to put that method, here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#result').empty();
    var userInput = $('input').val()
      $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url:"https://www.reddit.com/r/" + userInput + ".json?jsonp",
        success:success
      })
  })
  function success(response){
    var result ="";
    var zero = "0"
    $.each(response, function(index, value){
        var list = response.data.children
        $.each(list.slice(1).slice(0, 12), function(index,value){
            var thumbnail = value.data.thumbnail
            result += "<li>" + "<img src='" + thumbnail + "'/>"
            $('#result').html(result)
        })
    })
  }
})
```

Also if you have any idea how to structure my code so I only need to make one $.each loop, that would be help also!

Thanks a tonne,

James

Comment: use `jquery.filter` on condition `return thumbnail !== "" && thumbnail !== null` in your `success`

Comment: Please below link I think this will solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245231/how-do-i-filter-the-returned-data-from-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the item with falsy thumbnail in the list (null or undefined, among others) by using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)

```
var list = response.data.children.filter(function(item) {
   return item.data.thumbnail;
});

$.each(list, function(index,value){
   var thumbnail = value.data.thumbnail;
   $('#result').html(result)
})
```

Comment: It seems to be not causing any erorrs, some thumbnails have a value of 'self' which isn't a URL so I can't use it.  I'm trying to try an if statement, but dont no where to go after with.

if(value.data.thumbnail == self){
** Skip to next one**

}

Comment: You can add it to the filter condition. `return item.data.thumbnail && item.data.thumbnail !== 'self';`

Answer (score 0):

`Promises` will help you to have a more structured code, 
`Array.prototype.reduce` will help you to avoid unnecessary iterations.

```js
function loadRedditData(keyword) {
  return jQuery
    .get(`https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/${keyword}.json`, {jsonp: ''})
    .then(res => res.data.children.slice(1, 12))
    .then(data => (
      data.reduce((html, item) => {
        let card = `<h5>${item.data.name}</h5>`;
        
        if(item.data.thumbnail) {
          card = `<img src="${item.data.thumbnail}" />`;
        }
        
        return html.concat(`<div class="card">${card}</div>`);
      }, '')
    ))
    .then(html => jQuery('#result').html(html))
  ;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    return loadRedditData(jQuery('input').val() || 'Ecmascript 6');
  });

})
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Load Your Data</button>
<input value="javascript" />
<hr />
<section id="result"></section>
```